# use lzw with httpurlconnection in android

Tags: android, performance, gzip, lzw

we are trying to minimise the json data footprint for our android native application but, from the android developer pages we can see that by default android uses gzip compression

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

However we were looking as to how to reduce the footprint further using lzw etc. since the json files we  send over are huge. If there is any way to get the same compression level in gzip that is also fine.

We are looking at the following method for customising the compression algorithm

http://twistbyte.com/applications/receive-compressed-json-with-android-app

If there is any android port for any such library please let us know.